# Cant write (save) spark dataframe in parquet fromat to S3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 12 smaller parquet files which I successfully read them and combine them.  I'm trying to save the combined dataframe in one parquet file in S3 but It shows me an error

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('combine_files').getOrCreate()
```

the files are in this dir

```
df=spark.read.parquet("s3://aws-emr-resources-359367213591-us-east-1/taxi_data_2020/*").coalesce(1)

df.count()
24649092
```

when I try to write (save the dataframe in parquet format in s3 folder)

```
df.write.parquet("s3://aws-emr-resources-359367213591-us-east-1/merged_data_2020/single")
```

it shows me this error, how i can solve it

```
An error was encountered:
```

An error occurred while calling o268.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:199)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SQLExecution$$executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionMetrics$.withMetrics(QueryExecutionMetrics.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SQLExecution$$withMetrics(SQLExecution.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:305)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:291)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:586)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 13, ip-172-31-75-44.ec2.internal, executor 6): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:411)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1405)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:417)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainDoubleDictionary
at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToInt(ParquetDictionary.java:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getInt(OnHeapColumnVector.java:298)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:585)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:246)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:252)
... 10 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2171)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2159)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2158)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2158)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2419)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2368)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2357)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:822)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:171)
... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:411)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1405)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:417)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainDoubleDictionary
at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToInt(ParquetDictionary.java:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getInt(OnHeapColumnVector.java:298)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:585)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:246)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:252)
... 10 more

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 847, in parquet
self._jwrite.parquet(path)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o268.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:199)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SQLExecution$$executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionMetrics$.withMetrics(QueryExecutionMetrics.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SQLExecution$$withMetrics(SQLExecution.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:305)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:291)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:249)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:586)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 13, ip-172-31-75-44.ec2.internal, executor 6): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:411)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1405)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:417)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainDoubleDictionary
at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToInt(ParquetDictionary.java:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getInt(OnHeapColumnVector.java:298)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:585)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:246)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:252)
... 10 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2171)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2159)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2158)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2158)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2419)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2368)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2357)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:822)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:171)
... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:411)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1405)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:417)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainDoubleDictionary
at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToInt(ParquetDictionary.java:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getInt(OnHeapColumnVector.java:298)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:585)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:246)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:252)
... 10 more

Answer (score 0):

```
df.write.parquet("s3a://aws-emr-resources-359367213591-us-east-1/merged_data_2020/single")
```

Comment: still facing the same problem An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o97.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

Comment: @AbdelhamidShaat This issue occured randomy on my end as well. Have you figured out any solution ?

Comment: do you show run task? spark-shell or spark-submit?